# Linear dependence in a complex vector space, and viewed as a real vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $M$ is a linearly dependent set in a complex vector space $X$, Is $M$ linearly dependent in $X$, regarded as a real vector space??

My attempt

Say $dim X = n$ regarded a comlex vector space. We know number of vectors in $M$ is $<$ than $n$. since $M$ is linearly dependent. We know $\dim X = 2n$ if $X$ is regarded a real vector space. Therefore, number of vectors in $M < n < 2n \implies $ $M$ is linearly dependent if $X$ is regarded as a real vector space. IS this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To comment on your attempt:

1. The number of vectors in $M$ can be literally *anything* from one to infinity. If $M$ was linearly **independent**, then it would have at most $n$ vectors.
2. If a number of vectors in a set is smaller than the dimension of the space, you can conclude nothing about the (in)dependence of those vectors.

   If it's strictly greater than $\dim X$ (which is an assumption that you do not have), then you can conclude that its vectors are linearly dependent.

Sasha already gave you an example which shows that your initial statement is not true, so I'll just add that these two are:

> If $M$ is a linearly **independent** set in a complex vector space $X$, then $M$ is also linearly **independent** in $X$ regarded as a real vector space.

and

> If $M$ is a linearly dependent set in a **real** vector space $X$, then $M$ is also linearly dependent in $X$ regarded as a **complex** vector space.

These both boil down to the fact that you have a wider choice of factors in $\mathbb{C}$ than you have in $\mathbb{R}$. So, you can have $i \cdot 1 = i$, but not $x \cdot [1\ 0]^T = [0\ 1]^T$, no matter what $x \in \mathbb{R}$ you choose.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it is the case. Elements $1,i\in\mathbb{C}$ ($1$-dimensional complex vector space) are dependent over $\mathbb{C}$, but are independent over $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M= \{z_1, z_2, \dots,z_n\}$.
Then $c_1.z_1+c_2.z_2+\dots+c_n.z_n=(0,0)$ implies that there exists some $c_i$ not equals to zero, for $i=1,2,\dots,n$. If $z_i=(x_i,y_i)$, for $x_i,y_i$ belonging to real numbers, then we have,
$c_1.x_1+c_2.x_2+\dots+c_n.x_n=0$ and $c_1.y_1+c_2.y_2+\dots+c_n.y_n=0$ with some non-zero $c_i$.
It leads us to the conclusion that $M$ is linearly dependent in $X$, regarded as a real vector space.

Comment: This is just wrong. While you may view complex numbers as being pairs of real numbers, you cannot consider elements $z_i$ of an arbitrary complex _vector space_ as being pairs (that would be its "real" and "imaginary" parts). So you cannot split $z_i$ into components $x_i$, $y_i$ to begin with. But even if you could, one would have $x_i$, $y_i$ _vectors_, not real numbers. And you are fundamentally overlooking the fact that multiplication by _complex_ coefficients $c_i$ would mix "real" and "imaginary" parts of vectors: you cannot conclude that $c_1.x_1+c_2.x_2+\dots+c_n.x_n=0$ separately.

Comment: For a concrete example, $v=\binom 11$ and $\def\i{{\mathbf i}}w=\binom \i\i$ are linearly dependent in $\Bbb C^2$ as complex vector space, since $v+\i w=0$. However our conclusion that they are also linearly dependent in $\Bbb C^2$ as _real_ vector space is wrong; there is no dependence relation with nonzero _real_ coefficients.