# Why are the elements $1,i∈\mathbb{C}$, (1) dependent in $\mathbb{C}$, (2) but independent in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: vector-spaces, complex-numbers

Is it because

(1) We can choose $k_{1}=1$ and $k_{2}=i$, such that $1.k_{1}+i.k_{2}=0$ but $k_{1}\neq 0$ and $k_{2}\neq 0$.

(2) $i \notin \mathbb{R}$.

I am trying to understand the second answer to [Linear dependence in a complex vector space, and viewed as a real vector space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679037/linear-dependence-in-a-complex-vector-space-and-viewed-as-a-real-vector-space)

Comment: (1) is fine, but for (2) it's more correct to say "There are no $k_1, k_2\in \Bbb R$ such that $1\cdot k_1 + i\cdot k_2 = 0$, apart from $k_1 = k_2 = 0$", and then, of course, _prove_ that statement in some fitting manner. $i \notin \Bbb R$ will probably be an important part in such a proof, but it is not a full answer by itself.

Comment: @Jonas I daresay I know very well what real and complex numbers are. For instance, $\Bbb C$ can be (and is very often) seen as a two-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb R$, and in that interpretation, the vectors $1, i\in \Bbb C$ are linearly independent. That is what (2) is about.

Comment: @Arthur, thank you for your comment. For (2), why do $k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$ have to be in $\mathbb{R}$. For the definition of linear independence it says that $k_{n}$ have to be any scalars so why can't $k_{1},k_{2}\in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @gbd: "Scalar" does not have any fixed meaning; its meaning depends on context.  When you are talking about "linear dependence over $\mathbb{R}$", that means precisely that you are taking "scalar" to mean "element of $\mathbb{R}$".

Comment: @EricWofseym but why is it when we are working with vector space, for example $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then $k_n$ are scalars not vectors i.e. $k_n$ are not elements of $R^{n}$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.  I think you may be confusing "linear independence _in_ a vector space" with "linear independence _over_ a field".

Comment: @EricWofsey, you said that when we are talking about real numbers then $k_{n}$ "scalars" mean element of $\mathbb{R}$ and when we are talking about complex numbers then $k_{n}$ "scalars" mean element of $\mathbb{C}$ does that mean that when we are working with vector space then $k_n$ are vectors?

Comment: @gbd: No, you're confusing two different things.  When we talk about a vector space, we are both talking about the vector space itself and the field of scalars.  When we work with the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$, the vector space is $\mathbb{R}^n$ but the field of scalars is still $\mathbb{R}$.  See [this comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2071112/why-are-the-elements-1-i%e2%88%88-mathbbc-1-dependent-in-mathbbc-2-but-in?noredirect=1#comment4252886_2071124).

Comment: If you want a more detailed explanation of this distinction, I would suggest asking about it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there exist real numbers $k_1,k_2$ such that $1.k_1+i.k_2=0$, then $(k_1+ik_2)(k_1-ik_2) = k_1^2 +k_2^2 = 0$. As $k_1$ and $k_2$ are both real, this means that $k_1^2$ and $k_2^2$ are non-negative, hence $k_1^2$ and $k_2^2$ must both be zero (as otherwise $k_1^2+k_2^2=0$ would not be true).

It follows that both $k_1$ and $k_2$ are zero and so $1$ and $i$ are independent over the reals by definition of linear independence over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Why do $k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$ have to be real? Don't they have to be just any scalars?

Comment: scalars are dependent on the field you are working over. In this case, $(1)$ is asking you about when your field of scalars is the complex numbers, $(2)$ is asking you about when your field of scalars is the real numbers.

Comment: This answer, while not incorrect, seems misleading to me.  In order to talk about multiplication of complex numbers, you presumably need to have some _definition_ of what a complex number actually is, and from that definition it will be very easy to see directly that $1\cdot k_1+i\cdot k_2=0$ implies $k_1=k_2=0$.  (Although I suppose if your definition of complex numbers is something like $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$, then your argument actually is one of the easiest ways to see $1$ and $i$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: @DanRust, but why is it when we are working with vector space, for example $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then $k_n$ are scalars not vectors i.e. $k_n$ are not elements of $R^{n}$.

Comment: @EricWofsey if you're only given the complex numbers axiomatically $\{a+bi\mid a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and given a rule for multiplication of $(a+bi)(c+di)$, and multiplication by (real) scalars etc, then it's easy to show that this forms a real vector space, but it's not immediate that $1$ and $i$ are independent from this definition. I'll admit it's definition dependent though.

Comment: Yeah, that sort of axiomatic definition is what I had in mind when I said "something like $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$".

Comment: @gbd because that's the definition of a scalar. A scalar is an element of the field over which you are working. Vector spaces come with several pieces of information: The set itself (the name of each element), the rule for adding them, the distinguished element $0$ etc., but most importantly, you have to specify the field of scalars. A vector space inherently comes equipped with a field of scalars, and the vector space $\mathbb{C}$ over $K=\mathbb{C}$ or $K=\mathbb{R}$ are two *different* vector spaces (even though we often give them the same label $\mathbb{C}$).

Answer (score 0):

Vector space $\mathbb C(\mathbb R)$ can be identified as $\mathbb R^2$ for which $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are basis elements.